# How can I change an editor command in vim?

Tags: vim, vundle, neovim

I use fish shell, and that breaks Vundle. I want to change the `:PluginInstall` command, so that it executes

```
set shell=/bin/bash
PluginInstall
set shell&
```

I tried to write a [function](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/23.html) but that doesn't seem to be the way to do it.

Comment: Why do you care to set Vim's `shell` back to `fish`?  You'll never use Vim's shell interactively.  Also, `shell=fish` will break many other plugins.

Comment: because I use Neovim terminal mode

Comment: Then perhaps ask on Neovim's tracker.  A workaround for `shell=fish` has been added to Vim some time ago, it's probably also needed on Neovim.

Comment: Create an issue on the Vundle bug tracker. This is a bug they should fix. Making a patch/pull request yourself is even better! I use `tcsh`, which is also not Bourne compatible and have fixed it in Syntastic, vim-go, and vim-plug.

Comment: This how it was fixed in vim-go btw: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/pull/988/files